# increment in array

Tags: php

I have earlier asked this question but by mistake, I deleted the question so reposting it as another question.

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST['Receipts'])) {
$params['Date'] = '31 Jan 2000';
$response = $Auth->request('GET', $Auth->url('Receipts/Travel', 'core'), $params);
if ($Auth->response['code'] == 200) {
    $receipt = $Auth->parseResponse($OAuth->response['response'], $Auth->response['format']);
    pr($receipt->Receipts);
} else {
    outputError($Auth);

}
```

}

This piece of code provides me with the Travel receipts as on 31 Jan 2000 and now I wanted to include a foreach loop so that I could get Travel receipts for whole 12 months of 2000 like 28 Feb 2000, 31 Mar 2000 and so on till 31 Dec 2000.

I am a beginner and hence tried the following basic foreach loop which didnt work as I know I misplaced the logic.

```
    if (isset($_REQUEST['Receipts'])) {
 $months = array( " 31 Jan 2000"," 28 Feb 2000"," 31 Mar 2000","30 Apr 2000","31 May 2000","30 Jun 2000","31 Jul 2000"," 31 Aug 2000","30 Sep 2000","31 Oct 2000","30 Nov 2000","31 Dec 2000");
  foreach ($months as $month){
    $params['Date'] = '31 Jan 2000';
$response = $Auth->request('GET', $Auth->url('Receipts/Travel', 'core'), $params);
if ($Auth->response['code'] == 200) {
    $receipt = $Auth->parseResponse($OAuth->response['response'], $Auth->response['format']);
    pr($receipt->Receipts);
} else {
    outputError($Auth);
}
}
```

}

I know this would be pretty basic but as for as I concerned this is a big issue and any help on this case would be highly helpful for me. Thanks

Hi, is there any way that instead of directly storing month values[ 31 Jan 2000"," 28 Feb 2000"," 31 Mar 2000"...] in an array, the code itself should increment for different months. Because providing all the month values of a year is kind of hardcoding and for other years I need to edit it often. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `foreach` but must've forgot to plug it into the `$params` variable.

```
foreach ($months as $month){
   $params['Date'] = $month;
...
}
```

Does it solve the problem?

Comment: yes, I forgot the $params variable. thanks It worked.

Comment: Hi, is there any way that instead of directly storing month values[ 31 Jan 2000"," 28 Feb 2000"," 31 Mar 2000"...] in an array, the code itself should increment for different months. Because providing all the month values of a year is kind of hardcoding and for other years I need to edit it often. Any ideas on this? Thanks